# How do I connect to a code-first created localdb database using database explorer?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a database in an MVC 4 project that has so far been entirely managed via Code First and Migrations. I now want to go in and change some of the data by hand. How can I connect to the localdb instance using Database Explorer within Visual Studio 2012? The connection string is as follows:

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-mydb-20120830192823;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-mydb-20120830192823.mdf
```

I have an App_Data folder in my project, but the .mdf named in the connection string is not in there.

I have tried connecting to '(LocalDb)', 'LocalDb', '.SQLEXPRESS' and various other things in the Add Connection dialog, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh, it was '.\SQLEXPRESS' I needed to connect to.